# rails storing id's from reference table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I submit a text field into `user_items` I want it to take the `ID` of that item from `master_list_items` and place it into the `master_list_items_id` column under `user_items`

I have added master_list_items.rb -- but I'm not sure of the relationship to add..

Any suggestions?

**master_list_items**

```
+----------------------+----+
| name                 | id |
+----------------------+----+       
| Item A               | 1  |
| Item B               | 2  |
| Item C               | 3  |
+----------------------+----+
```

**user_items**

```
+---- +----------+----------------------+
| uid | item     | master_list_item_id  |
+-----+----------+----------------------+
| 2   | Item A   | NULL                 |
| 7   | Item C   | NULL                 |
| 9   | Item C   | NULL                 |
+-----+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess your models are done like this:

```
class MasterListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_items
end

class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :master_list_item
end
```

To implement what you're looking for the solution would probably be like this:

```
master_list_item = MasterListItem.create( :name => "Item 1" )
user_item = master_list_item.user_items.build( :name => "User Item 1" )
user_item.save
```

This should yield the results you're looking for.

For more on relationships refer to the [associations module on ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).